# Сглаживание (smooth) одномерный (двумерных) массивов

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Сглаживание массива - замена каждого соседнего элемента средним арифметисеским его соседей 
Если можно пример кода

Comment: Вы же сами написали - *замена каждого соседнего элемента средним арифметисеским его соседей*. Что тут непонятного? Ну хоть что-то вы знаете в языке С?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n =... 
float[n] a = {...};
float[n] d; 
d[0] = a[0]; d[n-1] = a[n-1];
for(int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
{  
    d[i] = (a[i-1] + a[i+1])/2;
}
```